# Python logging to QTextEdit

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, pyside

I want to upgrade my logs parts to fit the logging module.

My application is already quite advanced and uses PySide for GUI. I would like to set handlers to generate different log files, but also one to write to a `QTextEdit` console-like widget...

For now a `writeLog` function writes to a main log file (containing all logs generated during execution), and to the `QTextEdit`, and in addition, I write to separate files for some specific parts of my application.

---

How can I achieve this? (the simpler the better). Do I need to subclass Handler class? (would be quite above my level for now in Python, but if well guided, why not I guess) Or did I simply miss something in the doc?

Comment: Hm, there is a potential pitfall. If your advanced PySide GUI crashes then the logger won't be able to show its log output, will it? Wouldn't it be better to log in a file or the console instead? Otherwise I think subclassing the handler and connecting a Qt signal with a slot updating the QTextEdit is pretty straightforward. Just do it. What exactly is holding you back?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed, if the application crashes in the middle of something, log will fail at this point (with a manual 'with open() as...' file creation but also with logging)... Maybe I could add log to console indeed. Anyway, I have a console embedded in the GUI and I want to be able to log to it. So thanks for confirming the subclassing idea. Nothing holds me back, except the fact I am quite beginner in Python ^^ Plus, this application is really used for a short time as a tool for the dev team so I'll keep the idea but maybe not take the time for this extra dev yet...

Answer (score 6):

You can use custom logger instead of your `writeLog` function. It's quite easy. example:

```
class GuiLogger(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        self.edit.append_line(self.format(record))  # implementation of append_line omitted

h = GuiLogger()
h.edit = yourTextEditWidget  # this should be done in __init__
logging.getLogger().addHandler(h)
```

and now `logging.info("nice")` will save log to GUI widget.

Answer (score 1):

To use QTextEdit this has to changed

```
class GuiLogger(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        self.edit.append_line(self.format(record))
```

with

```
class GuiLogger(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        self.edit.textCursor().insertText(self.format(record))
```